# Django turn lists into one list

Tags: python, django

I want to put this data into one list so i can sort it by timestamp. I tried itertools chain but that didn't really work.
Thank you for your help :)

I'm very bad at making clear what i want to do so im sorry upfront if this takes some explaning.

If i try a chain i get the value back like this.

I want to display it on the html page like this :

date, name , rating, text (newline)
likes comments

Which would work the way i did it but if i want to sort it by time, it wouldn't work so i tried to think of a way to make it into a sortable list. Which can be displayed. Is that understandable ?

['Eva Simia', 'Peter Alexander', {'scale': 5, 'value': 5}, {'scale': 5, 'value': 5}, 1, 0, 1, 0]

it should look like this:
['Peter Alexander, scale:5, value:5, 1,0]
['Eva Simia, scale:5, value:5, 1,0]

```
for i in user:
    name.append(i['name'])

for i in next_level:
    rating_values.append(i['rating'])

for i in comment_values:
    comments_count.append(i['count'])

for i in likes_values:
    likes_count.append(i['count'])

for s in rating_values:
    ratings.append(s['value'])

for s in date:
    ratings.append(s['date'])   

ab = itertools.chain([name], [rating_values], 
                     [comments_count], [likes_values],
                     [comment_values], [date])
list(ab)
```

Comment: Please explain why it didn't work? What were you expecting? What did you really get

Comment: Changed really long code line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated after clarification:**

The problem as I understand it:

- You have a dataset that is split into several lists, one list per field.
- Every list has the records in the same order. That is, `user[x]`'s rating value is necessarily `rating_values[x]`.

You need to merge that information into a single list of composite items. You'd use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) for that:

```
merged = zip(user, next_level, comment_values, likes_values, rating_values, date)

# merged is now [(user[0], next_level[0], comment_values[0], ...), 
#                (user[1], next_level[1], comment_values[1], ...), 
#                ...]
```

From there, you can simply sort your list using [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
result = sorted(merged, key=lambda i: (i[5], i[0]))
```

The `key` argument must be a function. It is given each item in the list once, and must return the key that will be used to compare items. Here, we build a short function on the fly, that returns the date and username, effectively telling things will be sorted, first by date and if dates are equal, then by username.

**[Past answer about `itertools.chain`, before the clarification]**

```
ab = list(itertools.chain(
    (i['name'] for i in user),
    (i['rating'] for i in next_level),
    (i['count'] for i in comment_values),
    (i['count'] for i in likes_values),
    (i['value'] for i in rating_values),
    (i['date'] for i in date),
))
```

The point of using `itertools.chain` is usually to avoid needless copies and intermediary objects. To do that, you want to pass it iterators.
`chain` will return an iterator that will iterate through each of the given iterators, one at a time, moving to the next iterator when current stops.

Note every iterator has to be wrapped in parentheses, else python will complain. Do not make it square brackets, at it would cause an intermediary list to be built.

Comment: Thank you added an update =) hopefully it is better to understand now =)

Comment: Much better yes. So you have several lists, all of them in the same order, and each list gives data for one field? Like, first user is `[user[0], next_level[0], ]` and then  second user is `[user[1], next_level[1], ...]` and so on?

Comment: Yes :))) is that possible ?

Comment: ah  my current list looks like this [user[1], user[2] ..... ] [nextlevel[1] , nextlevel .....]  or like the example above and that is not useful or smart ^^. Like you describe it above is like I want to use it. Make a list like [user[1], next_level[1], timestamp[1] .....] sort list [0,1,2,3] by timestamp for example

Comment: I edited, it should be much closer to what you want.

Comment: thank you, exactly what i wanted. If i try to render it in the template i get an error. Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'i[0]'. How can i render it now inside the template ? That it looks like the list just without the brackets?

Comment: `{% for item in result %}Name: {{item.0}} / next_level: {{item.1}} / ...{% endfor %}`

Comment: Realized an issue ^^ it is not possible to store more then one value in comment_values when i try to list it with item. right? so if i have for example: user message and more then one comment refering to that message

Comment: You could, it's just a matter of passing it around and then displaying it correctly at the end (with a properly nested loop).

Answer (score 0):

You can join list by simply using `+`.

```
l = name + rating_values + comments_count + ...
```

Comment: isn't that the same as using `itertools.chain()` which didn't work for the OP?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I was not totally aware what `chain()` does. You're obviously right!

Comment: Updated it so i hope it is easier to understand now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
date, rating_values,likes_values,comment_values,next_level,user = (list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(date, rating_values,likes_values,comment_values,next_level,user))))
```

Comment: Please explain your answer so other readers may understand it.